# Drawing each sprite at different location

Tags: pygame

I can draw multiple sprites but they are all on top of each other at (0,0). How would I make each sprite appear after one another in a row?

My Rect class and Draw function:

```
class Rect(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,color,width,height,value=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.value = value
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
    def change_value(self,color,value):
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.value=value

def DrawRects():
    rect1 = Rect(red, boxW, boxH)
    rect2 = Rect(black, boxW, boxH)
    rects.add(rect1, rect2)

    rects.draw(screen)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the question. Rewrite the attributes to the Rect() class constructor. Use a method to receive arguments of desired starting x,y of where to start rendering sprites at.

```
class DrawableRect(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,color,width,height,value=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.value = value
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
    def change_value(self,color,value):
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.value=value

def DrawRects(start_x, start_y, rect_spacing, red):
    current_x_pos = start_x
    for rect_num in range(0,8):
        rect = DrawableRect(colour_list[rect_num], boxW, boxH)
        rect.rect.x = current_x_pos
        rect.rect.y = start_y
        current_x_pos = current_x_pos + rect.rect.width + rect_spacing
        rects.add(rect)
    rects.draw(screen)
```

In main loop:

`DrawRects(screen_width*0.01, screen_height*0.1,10,red)`